# Is there a way to change width and height of the html tag?

Tags: html

I noticed that the html tag won't change it's height or width. I was wondering if there was a way to do that or if the html tag will always fill the available space?

for example:

```
html{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: You could give more details on what are you trying to do so we could figure out some solution for you.

Comment: What do you mean with "change width and height of an html tag"? Which tag?

Comment: The html tag itself. (<html>). This is mostly a curiosity question. Don't know if that kind of thing is allowed here.

Comment: Tags are part of the markup... the width/height they have is the size of the text in your IDE.  I think you want to change the width/height of the element they become.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the dimensions of the `html` element in CSS just as you have done in your sample code. You can see that they are applied, e.g. by adding `outline: solid red` to rule.

Setting the dimensions does not have much effect, though. In particular, setting background color on `html` still affects the entire canvas. According to CSS 2.1 spec, section 14.2 [The background](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background), it is recommended to set background on `body` rather than `html`. If you set on `html`, it “becomes the background of the canvas and covers the entire canvas”.

And if you set background on `body`, a special rule applies, saying that the background will be used for the entire canvas (as if it had been set on `html`), if the `html` element has transparent background and no background image, which is the default. Thus, you can avoid the effect by also setting background on `html`. Example:

```
html { 
    background: white;
}
body {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background: blue;
}
```

I don’t see why you would do that, though. If you really want the page content appear in a 300 by 300 pixels box, the normal way is to wrap it in a `div` container and set dimensions and background on it:

```
<style>
.stuff {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background: blue;
}
</style>
<body><div class=stuff>Content goes here.</div></body>
```